# Error for array_merge() in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I really got a big problem because when I login in app.php environment I got a warning .By the way I am using symfony2.

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Model\User.php
>   line 181

this is mu User.php

```
 public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
    ));
}

/**
 * Unserializes the user.
 *
 * @param string $serialized
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    $data1 = unserialize($serialized);
    // add a few extra elements in the array to ensure that we have enough keys when unserializing
    // older data which does not include all properties.
    $data = array_merge($data1, array_fill(0, 2, null));

    list(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id
    ) = $data;
}
```

Can you help me solve this one?

Comment: Are you sure that the $serialized is a serialized form of an array you are passing? Can you put the calling statement. Otherwise add the condition before merging - is_array($data1) {...}

Comment: yes because I tried to use var_dump after unserialize and it gives me the data.

Comment: Can you take that data and try array_merge explicitly. If that is working it should work.

Comment: can you clarify on how can I put the condition before merging?

Comment: @ xammeil posted as an answer.

Comment: as I check the log in profiler there's a warning "WARNING - Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Matrix\MatrixUserBundle\Entity\User' 
Context: {"type":2,"file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Editracker\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\ClassMetadataInfo.php","line":878,"scream":0}"

Comment: how can I solve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76602/discussion-between-xammeil-and-sanjay-kumar-n-s).

Comment: I couldn't join. There was no comment box for me there.

Comment: Normally, that the serialized data string comes from the session and it's possible that has been corrupted somehow. The "Erroneous data format" error would seem to suggest that. Can you confirm that you're getting a proper array? PHP doesn't seem to think it is. Try clearing the session, and seeing if it continues.

Comment: ahm,,,, how can I clear the session  coz i'm just new in symfony

Comment: can you help me how to do it...? coz I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the is_array condition like this:

```
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
    ));
}

/**
 * Unserializes the user.
 *
 * @param string $serialized
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    $data1 = unserialize($serialized);
    // add a few extra elements in the array to ensure that we have enough keys when unserializing
    // older data which does not include all properties.
    if (is_array($data1)) {
        $data = array_merge($data1, array_fill(0, 2, null));
    }

    list(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id
    ) = $data;
}
```

Comment: the error is replace with another error again . It says "Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Model\User.php on line 198"

Comment: I got it its already working , instead of $data in list() I put $data1. thanks

Comment: Then that will not be the expected output rt. means $data1 will not be the mergerd array.

Comment: it is okay already ,,, my problem now is that the app_dev.php is returning blank page while the app.php is working perfectly ,,, how can I solve it?

Comment: I fix it already the merging, but my problem now is that the app_dev.php have no content as in blank page., while in the app.php is working perfectly. When I got an that error earlier, the array_merging , the app_dev.php also have that  but then when I fix it already the app_dev.php return blank page,.. how can I solve this?